# Can you join two tables to get the next row

Tags: t-sql, join

Trying to write a query which will validate a value derieved from a series of transactions.

Table A contains columns `Code, Date, Value` and table B contains `Code, Date, Value`.

Both tables contain multiple instances of the same code.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get every row from Table A, and join onto it the row from Table B that has the same stock item, and is the first date that is less than the Table A date.

e.g.

Table A

```
OC001, 2019-01-01, £10
```

Table B has

```
OC001, 2018-10-15, £6
OC001, 2018-11-30, £8
OC001, 2019-01-02, £11
```

Expected result is

```
OC001, 2019-01-01, £10, OC001, 2018-11-30, £8
```

As 2018-11-30 is closest to 2019-01-01 and OC001 = OC001

Tried different joining approaches, but reaching the limit of what I can construct.

```
SELECT
  r.Code,
  cc.StockCode,
  r.Date,
  cc.InvDate
FROM tableA as r
JOIN tableB as cc ON r.Code = cc.StockCode AND r.Date >= cc.InvDate
ORDER BY r.Code, r.Date, cc.InvDate
```

The query works for the most part, but it's duplicating the results when there's more than one matching result in table B.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining one entry on all entrys with the same Code and equal or greater Date. In that case you will probably will get always a big Resultset depending on the count of data inserted in your database.

To get the next transaction contained in the table you need to aggregat the data and get the on with the lowest InvDate:

```
SELECT r.Code,r.Date,MIN(cc.InvDate) 
FROM tableA as r 
JOIN table B as cc ON r.Code = cc.Code
WHERE r.Date >= cc.InvDate 
GROUP BY r.Code,r.Date
```

In this first all entrys of the table a with the same code will joined table b entrys and then filtered by the date that have to be greater equals. Because there will probably more then one entry left matching this condition u just need to get the one with the Min(InvDate) that is the one next in comparison to the table A entry. The Group By is needed because Min is an Aggregate function and because of that you need to group all your other properties you want to select. ( In case their is the possibility that there are entrys with the same date add Min(ID) So you will just get the one added first into the database)

To select it with value use:

```
SELECT r.Code,r.Date,r.Value,MIN(cc.InvDate),cc.Value
FROM tableA as r 
JOIN table B as cc ON r.Code = cc.Code
WHERE r.Date >= cc.InvDate 
GROUP BY r.Code,r.Date,r.Value,cc.Value
```

Think this should do your thing. Tested it with an own database table but used same approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely look at the `LAG` and `LEAD` functions

http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-lag/

> SQL LAG() is a window function that provides access to a row at a
>   specified physical offset which comes before the current row.
>
> In other words, by using the LAG() function, from the current row, you
>   can access data of the previous row, or from the second row before the
>   current row, or from the third row before current row, and so on.
>
> The LAG() function can be very useful for calculating the difference
>   between the current row and the previous row.